# Out of class definition of member function template in the presence of a member function of the same name - compiler divergence

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, language-lawyer, ambiguous

Consider this example of a class template containing a member function and a member function template both of which are named `f` followed by an attempt to define and specialize the member function template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A {
    void f();
    template<typename U>
    void f();
};

template<>
template<typename U>
void A<double>::f() { }

template<>
template<>
void A<double>::f<int>() { }
```

Is this legal? How should the member function template definition be written?

In the first definition of `f`, does the template declaration ensure that the member function template `f` should be selected rather than the member function `f` even though the template parameter does not appear in the type? I don't see any way to further disambiguate this as writing `::template f()`, `::f<U>()`, `::f<>()`, or a combination thereof does not seem to help.

Compiler results:

- clang: crashes with a stack trace at the specialization of `f<int>`
- Visual Studio: compiles successfully
- gcc: compile error (ambiguity regarding which `f` is being defined) at the first definition of `f`
- EDG: compiles successfully

By contrast, every compiler accepts the equivalent at namespace scope:

```cpp
namespace X {
    void f();
    template<typename T>
    void f();
}
template<typename T>
void X::f() { }
template<>
void X::f<int>() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a language defect report [DR 1665](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1665), which is in *drafting* status at this moment.

As mentioned there the standard says

> A normal (non-template) member function with a given name and type and a member function template of the same name, which could be used to generate a specialization of the same type, can both be declared in a class. When both exist, a use of that name and type refers to the non-template member unless an explicit template argument list is supplied.

And there is an open GCC bug report with an example very similar to yours: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64063